# Is there a flymake mode for Elisp itself?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use flymake in Emacs to check code written in several languages. However, I can't see any way to use flymake on elisp itself.

I'm aware of `elint-current-buffer`, and `byte-compile-file`, which both give useful warnings about undefined variables etc. Oddly, they don't always give the same errors: for example, elint doesn't warn about `(require 'cl)`. I've also tried `auto-compile-mode` (available on MELPA) but this still writes the warnings to a separate buffer.

I would really like my elisp code to be underlined when I make mistakes, as I type. How do I do this? I've configured flymake before, but that was with external programs, not Emacs itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Emacs wiki has [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeElisp) to say about flymake for emacs lisp, though it doesn't seem very complete.

[flycheck](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck) supports Emacs Lisp "out of the box", though.

Comment: I didn't know about flycheck, thanks. The EmacsWiki solution only checks that parens are balanced, which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Erefactor is pretty decent, and available from the wiki as well as melpa:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/erefactor.el

I also like to run checkdoc post-save:

```
 (defun emagician/run-checkdoc () 
   "run checkdoc on save if it is an elisp file"
   (if (and (eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)
            (> (length buffer-file-name)
               (length package-user-dir))
            (not (string= (concat package-user-dir "/")
                          (substring buffer-file-name 0 (+ 1 (length package-user-dir))))))
       (checkdoc)))

 (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'emagician/run-checkdoc)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about erefactor. However, it runs elint in a separate buffer. I ran `erefactor-elint` on erefactor.el and it gave me the following output: https://gist.github.com/Wilfred/5320601 .

For the record: I should also mention that [redshank](https://github.com/emacsmirror/redshank) is very similar to erefactor.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is `elisp-flymake-byte-compile` backend for flymake built in.
To enable add this to config:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'flymake-mode)
```